# Ruby strange behavior in keyword arguments mixed with positional

Tags: ruby, ruby-2.1, keyword-argument

Following code:

```
class Test
  attr_reader :args
  def initialize(arg1={}, arg2: 'value2')
    @args = [arg1, arg2]
  end
end
t = Test.new({key1: 'value1'})
puts t.args
```

I've expected to get printed out array with content `[{key1: 'value1'}, 'value2']`
but I'm getting:

```
test.rb:11:in `new': unknown keywords: val1, val2 (ArgumentError)
    from test.rb:11:in `<main>'
```

To be more strange, with the same testing class invoked with `{val1: 'value', val2: 'value2'}, arg2: 1)` as arguments i'm getting output: `{:val1=>"value", :val2=>"value2"}`

Where is the source of this behaviour, i'm missing something or it's a bug?
Ruby versions 2.1.1 and 2.1.2 was tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm currently using Ruby 2.1.0p0.

The "problem" can be simplified a little with the following example:

```
def foo(arg1 = {}, arg2: 'value1')
  [arg1, arg2]
end
```

Here, the method `foo` has one OPTIONAL argument `arg1` (with default `{}`) and one OPTIONAL keyword argument, `arg2`.

If you call:

```
foo({key1: 'value1'})
```

You get the error:

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: key1
        from (irb):17
        from /home/mark/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

The reason is that Ruby is attempting to match the only argument you gave (with keyword `key1`) to the only OPTIONAL keyword argument which is keyword `arg2`. They don't match, thus the error.

In the next example:

```
foo({val1: 'value', val2: 'value2'}, arg2: 1)
```

We get the result:

```
=> [{:val1=>"value", :val2=>"value2"}, 1]
```

This makes sense because I provided two arguments. Ruby can match `arg2: 1` to the second keyword argument and accepts `{val1: 'value', val2: 'value2'}` as a substitute for the first optional argument.

I do not consider the behaviors above a bug.

Comment: "one REQUIRED keyword argument, arg2." In your example, `arg2` is **not** required. To make it required, you would have to omit its default value (`'value1'`).

Comment: @Ajedi32 ah right, thanks for the correction. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, parameters resolution works the other way around from what you expected. In addition to konsolebox' answer, you can fix it by calling the constructor with an additional empty hash:

```
Test.new({key1: 'value1'}, {})
```

Answer (score -2):

Do it this way instead:

```
class Test
  attr_reader :args
  def initialize(arg1={}, arg2 = 'value2')  ## Changed : to =.
    @args = [arg1, arg2]
  end
end
t = Test.new({key1: 'value1'})
puts t.args.inspect
```

Output:

```
[{:key1=>"value1"}, "value2"]
```